# Column number detection using dataframe pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset appearing something like this:

```
empl_ID day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  day_5  day_6  day_7  day_8  day_9  day_10
 1        1      1      1      1      1      1      0      1      1      1
 2        0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0
 3        0      1      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1
 4        1      0      1      0      1      1      1      0      1      0
 5        1      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
 6        0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Each row indicates a record for an employee with employee id column 'empl_ID'. I am trying to write a code in Python that tracks the first occurrence of '1' in that record. For eg, empl_ID 1 the first time '1' occurs is in day_1 column so the label for that would be 1. For empl_ID 2, the first '1' occurs in column day_3, so the label will be 3. Similarly for all the other employees the labels will be 2,1,1 and 5 respectively. The resultant dataset looks something like this:

```
empl_ID day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  day_5  day_6  day_7  day_8  day_9  day_10  label
 1        1      1      1      1      1      1      0      1      1      1       1
 2        0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      0       3
 3        0      1      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1       2
 4        1      0      1      0      1      1      1      0      1      0       1
 5        1      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1       1
 6        0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1      1       5
```

If someone could please help me in writing a Python code for the above problem statement that would be very helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
s=df.set_index('empl_ID').idxmax(1).str.split('_').str[-1]
empl_ID
1    1
2    3
3    2
4    1
5    1
6    5
dtype: object
df['new']=s.values
```

Comment: This code works. But its returning me values like day_1, day_2, etc. Whereas I want it to return 1,2,...

Comment: @PrathameshMohite you can use regex, `df[your_col].str.extract('_(\d+)').astype(int)` or split `df[col].str.split('_')` and take the last value for the number.